# how to set date in android WeekView library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, calendar, android-library

I want to implement android WeekView in my calendar application.For that i used this `https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View library`. Now the problem is i cant set date in that WeekView .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never tried it because I never used this lib, but looking at the code, it seems this does what you want :

```
public void goToDate(Calendar date)
```

There is also a convenience method to go straight to today :

```
public void goToToday()
```

Answer (score 2):

`goToDate` is deprecated use `scrollToDate`

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.